# magit - triangle workflow with branches in fork

Tags: magit, git

I am using a triangle workflow. Upstream is called `upstream` and my forked repository is called `fork`.

I want to have multiple branches and each of those branches should exist both locally as well as in my forked remote repository. My plan is to synchronize from my fork into a local feature branch, work on it some, and push it to the corresponding branch on my forked repository again.

When I create the branches in `fork` (using Github's UI), I can't seem to get my local repository to pull that new branch.

I've tried pulling from `fork` as well as `upstream`, but neither works. I can only think I'm doing something stupid - anyone care to tell me what?

Comment: When you look at the status buffer (the one that shows up after you run `magit-status`), at the top, it should say what branch is tracked by the currently active branch (it calls it "Merge"). You can change the tracked branch by starting a push operation and then choosing `e` (elsewhere) option.

Comment: Does my answer address this question sufficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Cloning a repository does only create a single local branch. Usually that branch is named `master` and its upstream is `origin/master`. To create an additional branch `some-feature` from an existing *remote branch* `my-fork/some-feature`, you could use <kbd>b c</kbd> `my-fork/some-feature` <kbd>RET RET</kbd>.

The upstream of that branch would be `my-fork/some-feature`, but since you mentioned that you want to use a triangular work-flow, you probably want to use either `master` or `origin/master` as *upstream*. You can *change* the upstream using <kbd>b u</kbd>. You can also configure Magit to always adjust the upstream when creating a new local branch from a remote feature branch by customizing `magit-branch-adjust-remote-upstream-alist`.